# Fila de Execução de Script

Tags: php

Preciso saber se tem como fazer um lista de execução de script. Tenho 3 arquivos. a.php, aa.php, aaa.php para se executado via tarefa cron linux. Está programado para executar o a.php . O aa.php só poderá ser executado depois que o a.php for totalmente executado. O aaa.php somente depois do aa.php momento.

Gostaria de saber se tem alguma forma de fazer execução de um script depois que outro script ser totalmente executado

Comment: Olá, não percebi muito bem a sua questão mas no final da pagina colocar require_once resolve a sua questão?

Comment: Você poderia deixar apenas o a.php executando pelo cron e disparar o aa.php dentro do a.php e o aaa.php dentro do aa.php, alguma restrição quanto a essa ideia?